Can not change state from Dialog button onClick event
I am working on a Next.js app, and in one of the components, I have a DropdownMenu where one of its items launches a DialogAlert (both are Shadcn components). I am trying to control the dialog's open state with setIsDialogOpen, but it only works when there is a synchronous function before it (like the confirm button example). Otherwise, it won't work when I simply call setIsDialogOpen(false) from the cancel button action.
Here is the code to reproduce the problem:
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import {
 AlertDialog,
 AlertDialogAction,
 AlertDialogCancel,
 AlertDialogContent,
 AlertDialogDescription,
 AlertDialogFooter,
 AlertDialogHeader,
 AlertDialogTitle,
 AlertDialogTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/alert-dialog";
import {
 DropdownMenu,
 DropdownMenuContent,
 DropdownMenuItem,
 DropdownMenuTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dropdown-menu";
import { Loader2 } from "lucide-react";

export default function Home() {
 const [isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen] = useState(false);
 const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

 const handleCancelDelete = () => {
   setIsDialogOpen(false);
 };

 const handleDelete = async () => {
   setIsLoading(true);
   // Perform your delete operation here
   await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)); // Simulating an async operation
   setIsLoading(false);
 };

 return (
   <div>
     <DropdownMenu>
       <DropdownMenuTrigger>Dropdown</DropdownMenuTrigger>
       <DropdownMenuContent>
         <DropdownMenuItem>Action</DropdownMenuItem>
         <DropdownMenuItem
           onClick={() => setIsDialogOpen(true)}
           onSelect={(event) => event.preventDefault()}
         >
           <AlertDialog open={isDialogOpen} onOpenChange={setIsDialogOpen}>
             <AlertDialogTrigger>Delete</AlertDialogTrigger>
             <AlertDialogContent>
               <AlertDialogHeader>
                 <AlertDialogTitle>Are you absolutely sure?</AlertDialogTitle>
               </AlertDialogHeader>
               <AlertDialogFooter>
                 <AlertDialogCancel
                   onClick={() => {
                     alert("onClick works");
                     setIsDialogOpen(false);
                   }}
                 >
                   Cancel
                 </AlertDialogCancel>
                 {isLoading ? (
                   <Loader2 className="animate-spin" />
                 ) : (
                   <AlertDialogAction
                     onClick={async (e) => {
                       e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default action that closes the dialog
                       await handleDelete();
                       setIsDialogOpen(false);
                     }}
                   >
                     Continue
                   </AlertDialogAction>
                 )}
               </AlertDialogFooter>
             </AlertDialogContent>
           </AlertDialog>
         </DropdownMenuItem>
       </DropdownMenuContent>
     </DropdownMenu>
   </div>
 );
}


Here is a CodeSandbox link to reproduce the issue: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/cranky-montalcini-4432z5?embed=1&file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx%3A38%2C20

In your CodeSandbox link when I click the cancel button the dialog closes. Is that not the expected result?

Code in sandbox seems to work fine. Can you [edit] to clarify the problem and whatever your reproduction steps to produce it are?

Sorry guys when I found the solution I edited the sandbox code to test it but forgot to do the same here,

Maybe you also wants to close the dropdown on press of cancel button in alert dialog. To achieve this you need to convert the dropdown component from uncontrolled to controlled component by passing open and onChangeOpen props to dropdown component.
export default function Home() {
  const [isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleCancelDelete = () => {
    setIsDialogOpen(false);
  };

  const handleDelete = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    // Perform your delete operation here
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)); // Simulating an async operation
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  const [isDropDownOpen, setIsDropDownOpen] = useState(false);

  return (  
    <div> 
      <DropdownMenu open={isDropDownOpen} onOpenChange={() => {
        setIsDropDownOpen(!isDropDownOpen);
      }}>
        <DropdownMenuTrigger>Dropdown</DropdownMenuTrigger>
        <DropdownMenuContent>
          <DropdownMenuItem>Action</DropdownMenuItem>
          <DropdownMenuItem
            onClick={() => setIsDialogOpen(true)}
            onSelect={(event) => event.preventDefault()}
          >
            <AlertDialog open={isDialogOpen} onOpenChange={setIsDialogOpen}>
              <AlertDialogTrigger>Delete</AlertDialogTrigger>
              <AlertDialogContent>
                <AlertDialogHeader>
                  <AlertDialogTitle>Are you absolutely sure?</AlertDialogTitle>
                </AlertDialogHeader>
                <AlertDialogFooter>
                  <AlertDialogCancel
                    onClick={(e) => {
                      e.stopPropagation(); // Add this line to stop event propagation
                      setIsDropDownOpen(false);
                      setIsDialogOpen(false);
                    }}
                  >
                    Cancel
                  </AlertDialogCancel>
                  {isLoading ? (
                    <Loader2 className="animate-spin" />
                  ) : (
                    <AlertDialogAction
                      onClick={async (e) => {
                        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default action that closes the dialog
                        await handleDelete();
                        setIsDialogOpen(false);
                      }}
                    >
                      Continue
                    </AlertDialogAction>
                  )}
                </AlertDialogFooter>
              </AlertDialogContent>
            </AlertDialog>
          </DropdownMenuItem>
        </DropdownMenuContent>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </div>
  );
}


Nice thank you man! I really needed this

Implementing the suggested solution has caused a problem where all components in my app become unclickable and stuck after launching the dropdown menu, initiating the delete action, canceling it, and then scrolling down.
Note that I have a scrollable component with multiple components using that dropdown menu.
Do you have any thoughts about this?

The menu item like Action will not be clickable, you have to explicitly setDropDown(false) onClick of all the other menu items.

The issue I was facing is related to the event propagation in React. When you click the "Cancel" button, the click event is propagating up to the parent component (in this case, the DropdownMenuItem).
To fix this, I had to stop the event propagation by calling event.stopPropagation() in the onClick handler of the "Cancel" button. Here's the updated code of that part:
<AlertDialogCancel
  onClick={(e) => {
    e.stopPropagation(); // Add this line to stop event propagation
    setIsDialogOpen(false);
  }}
>
  Cancel
</AlertDialogCancel>

